# Limit function and DirectedInfinity as output: Interpretation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I tried to compute the following limit:

```
In[12]:= Limit[-A/2 x - 2 x, x -> +Infinity]

Out[12]= DirectedInfinity[-2 - A/2]
```

Does the output tell me that the software cannot evaluate the sign because it does not know the sign of A? And does it tell me that the solution is for sure plus or minus infinity?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `DirectedInfinity` is not a math notion, but  an invention of Mathematica developers only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the output tell me that the software cannot evaluate the sign because it does not know the sign of A?

In a way, yes. But it does not even assume `A` to be real. What if `A==I`?

> And does it tell me that the solution is for sure plus or minus infinity?

In a way, yes. But this is not *generally* correct. If `A==4`, then the answer is zero.

BTW newer versions give the answer as

```
(-2 - A/2) ∞
```

Also, in newer versions of `Limit` can do this:

```
Limit[-A/2 x - 2 x, x -> +Infinity, GenerateConditions -> True]

(* ConditionalExpression[(-2 - A/2) ∞, A != -4] *)
```

Finally, note that `Infinity` is also just [`DirectedInfinity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirectedInfinity.html) in disguise.

```
Infinity//FullForm
(* DirectedInfinity[1] *)

-Infinity//FullForm
(* DirectedInfinity[-1] *)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @Szabolcs. I have a question for you: A != -4 means that the limit constant*infinity makes sense because constant=/=0?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Yes, it is the reason why the condition is needed. Unfortunately, in your version of Mathematica (11.2 or earlier?) `Limit` does not have this feature.